# How can i add a facebook login for a web widget that would work in different domains

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a web widget and i want users to be able to login on it via Facebook, this widget would be embedded in different sites that would have different domains, but as you know, Facebook API only allow request from an specific domain.

Do you know how can i make it so Facebook authentication works from any domain ?

Comment: I dont think this is possible. For graph api, you need to create an appid which is specific to user domain. May be you can ask this information from users and automatically embed in widget code your users generate from your system.

Comment: @thomasbabuj Look at this https://www.zopim.com/ , is a chat widget, the allow google and facebook login, i think they use a server side method to authenticate .

Comment: They are probably using an iframe to render their widget on other sites – so that FB login still uses their domain (`zopim.com`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have a look at the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) in order to find some examples and also a guide in order to achieve your goal.

Also, I've found [oauth2-facebook](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-facebook) that should be a good practical answer to your quetion:

> This package provides Facebook OAuth 2.0 support for the PHP League's OAuth 2.0 Client.
>
> This package is compliant with PSR-1, PSR-2, PSR-4, and PSR-7. If you notice compliance oversights, please send a patch via pull request.

In order to connect the user facebook account with this protocol.